# Pass selected dropdown to controller- mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a simple select with a stores number, 
I have to pass the selected value to the controller to process the excel

it keeps passing empty value

here's my code:

```
    <form>
    <label>Select a Store</label>
    <form:select id="store" name="store" path="storeList">
        <form:option value="">ALL</form:option>
        <form:options items="${storeList}" />
    </form:select>
    here<c:out value= "${store }"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="store"/>
    <a href="exportReportByStore.do?store=${store}" smButtonStyling"> 
        <img src="/web/static/images/remove.png" /> Export to excel
    </a>
</form>
```

MY controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "exportReportByStore.do", method ={ RequestMethod.POST,  RequestMethod.GET}, produces = "application/vnd.ms-excel")
public void exportReportByStore(final StoreSignForm form, final HttpServletResponse response, final HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam(value="store") final String store) {
    LOG.debug("Store To export" + store);
    List<StoreSign> signsList = storeSignService.getSignsByStore(store);
```

.......
    }

If I hit the link directly with the store value, the code will work.
Can you please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the link to button and added the mapping to action=/exportReportByStore.do

```
    <form action="exportReportByStore.do" method="post">
    <label>Select a Store</label>
    <form:select id="store" name="store" path="storeList" style="top: 0px;width: 111px; ">
        <form:option value="">ALL</form:option>
        <form:options items="${storeList}" />
    </form:select>
    <input type="hidden" name="store"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Export" class="btnFwd gradient smButtonStyling">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do a post in your javascript. You can use the fetch api (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

If set in a href it does a GET method.

What do you mean with "If I hit the link directly with the store value, the code will work"?

Comment: I meant if I hit exportReportByStore.do?store=3 .. it will open the right link

Comment: Do  I need a JS?  because I'm using Java + Spring

Comment: I have POST in my controller, My issue is the selected value isn't passing to the controller : (

Comment: You are working with a REST controller so yes you need to do a POST request with JS.